# I have to back to user_registers when i create the payment for the user but i dont know how send the params to avoid the error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my controller:

class UserController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @id = params[:id]
    @payment= Payment.new 
    @user= params[:id]
end

def user_registers
  @id = params[:id]
  @payment= Payment.where("user_id= ?", @id)
  @user= User.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @user= User.find(params[:payment][:user_id])
    @payment= @user.payments.build(paymetData)
    if @payment.save

       # IN THIS PART SHOULD GO TO THE METHOD "user_registers"
    else

       # IN THIS PART SHOULD GO TO THE METHOD "user_registers" but i should 
       # appear an error

    end
end

def paymetData
   params.require(:payment).permit(:amount , :date)
end
```

NOTE: please help, guys and treated in every way that has come to my mind but the syntax is terrible and the references I was looking for did not help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have it, what you want is to build a relationship between your users and payments therefore when returning the method you need to get the user id, but remember that you sent the user objects with all their attributes, meaning that to your variable: id you can assign the user id using the user obeject that must contain the id as one of its variables, for that reason you first look for it within your user table by the: payment and: user_id and once located this gives you all the values ​​of the user that you sent now, you only have to send the necessary parameters to return to the user_registers function, which in this case would be the id of @user, that is, for the first if it is:

redirect_to user_registers (: id => @ user.id)

this is the syntax for rails 3 and 4 so there is no loss, you can add a, notice: to send a satisfactory message and in case the registration does not take place you do the same but with a negative message,

redirect_to user_registers (: id => @ user.id), notice: "ERROR"

that way you will return to your records avoiding the error the id_user not found or something like that.

luck and kind regards

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I tried it and it worked wonders, I can create the associations and go back to the user registers without any problem, I can reload the page and there is no problem, thanks